# Batch move dated folders

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to move dated folders within the same directory to another folder in the same one across multiple folders. So for example:

```
Path/to/dir/folderA/2015-5  
Path/to/dir/folderA/2015-8
```

need to be moved to `path/to/dir/folderA/2015` and the same with folder B, C, etc.
 Each has different months at the end but the year would be the same. So unsure on how to do it in a batch file for windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like...

```
for /d %%f in ("path\to\dir\folderA\2015*") do move "%%f" "path\to\dir\folderA\2015"
```

Comment: You should use quotes around the folder names (`"%%f"`, for instance) so that it won't break when a path contains spaces

Comment: Thanks, yes. This was just an illustration really as that's a separate issue, but I've updated to reflect this anyway.

Comment: Ah, ok now it works better. Thanks, that was actually easy.